# Label is not displaying in Symfony form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am facing a issue to display label.
Following is the code to generate form element.

```
$builder->add(
    'hearAboutUs', 'choice', [
        'choices' => ['Online Search'=>'Online Search',
            'Email'=> 'Email',
            'My Company' => 'My Company',
            'Colleague or Friend'=>'Colleague or Friend',
            'Existing Client' =>'Existing Client',
            'Direct Mail' => 'Direct Mail',
            'Other'=> 'Other',],
        'label' => 'How did you hear about us?',
        'required' => true,
        'expanded'=> true,
        'multiple' => false,
    ]
);
```

I am getting following output.[image]
As like "Notes" label "How did you hear about us" label is not displaying.

Comment: Where "Notes" come from? Isn't write directly in template?

Comment: How do you render the form? Can you show us your twig file?

Comment: Problem is as "Notes" are appearing while there is textarea instead if I am using choice label is not working but I am able to catch all the form data on controller.

Comment: For rendering,  {{ form(form) }} Where form is a object of form builder.

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine. The form itself is not the problem . Have you modified form theme etc?

Comment: I have updated a "Cart" entity only with getter/setter for hearAboutUs.

Comment: please post the view file, and these updates on the Cart entity.

Comment: I have posted code snippet in answer. Required also not working actually :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [override your form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) about choice widget.

You can do it like this :

1- Create a file named fields.html.twig in `app/Resources/views/form/`

2- In this file you have to extends [default twig layout](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) and override `checkbox_widget` adding `<label>` tag :

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
    </label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

3- Finally, tell Symfony to use it in your view like this :

```
{% form_theme form 'form/fields.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Hello, When I am commenting  'expanded'=> true property, label is showing as expected and required also working but when as soon as I am un-commenting this code label is getting hide and required also not working.

Comment: Hmm.. I have 39 elements in the form so trying your solution will need to manipulate whole structure. I am facing issue with above element only so it will be best if I get solution with this.

Answer (score 0):

**My View is looks like**

[image]

**My Updated Entity is**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this using JQuery.
On Form Load I am appending Label and for required I have handled this on the controller.
But this is not proper solution, but by this way my problem solved.